# How to initialize empty tables based on my rails schema without initializing in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm tasked to create a setup documentation from a project that will be passed on to new developers -- which needs them to setup the said project in their own systems.

Apparently, upon `rake db:schema:load` I found out that the project has model dependencies from files under `/config/initializers` which loads first before the models do.

I'm thinking that creating a script that would initialize empty tables first would be a good solution. Though I'm not sure how to do this without manually listing all the databases currently in use -- what if there is an additional table added in the future? This means I need to update the script everytime. Any way I can read the schema dynamically without actually running it (because, some models also need some things to be loaded from the `config/initializers` first.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of such a dependency? Might be worth to remove these dependencies. Did you consider switching to a SQL schema file and just using plain SQL to create the database?

Comment: @spickermann I'll update it with such examples. Sadly, this is a project that will just be turned over to me and right now I'm looking at the open-closed principle. At the meantime, I was instructed to setup the project without modifying anything -- this is also to find a way to setup the project for other new dev.